# Integrating numba and Rtree.nearest()

Tags: python-3.x, numba, r-tree

I've been desperately looking to apply @numba.njit(parallel=True) to the rtree.nearest() function, but I get error statement of "no pyobject".

Since Rtree is a ctypes wrapper function, how can I apply the ctypes library and then use numba on Rtree.nearest?

Below is the pseudo-code:

```
Initialise variable coordinates_tree
Initialise variable MAX
Initialise variable 2d_coordinates_array
Initialise variable EMPTY euclidean_distance_array

Function start

    Start for loop (MAX):
        
        Change 2d_coordinates to tuple

        Use rtree.nearest to find the nearest coordinate in tree (in form of object id)

        Convert to list to retrieve the nearest coordinate

        Convert to nearest coordinate numpy array   

        Calculate Euclidean distance between 2d_coordinate and nearest_coordinate

        Store the Euclidean distance in euclidean_distance_array

    Return euclidean_distance_array_array
```

Below is the documentation I've been investigating: https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/cfunc.html

Essentially, do I have to make sure the input and output are ctypes?